# Writing an EventLoop without using asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, event-loop

I'm getting very familiar with python's **asyncio**, the asynchronous programming in python, co-routines etc. 
I want to be able to executing several co-routines with my own custom made **eventloop**.

I'm curious if i can write my own **eventloop** without importing **asyncio** at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to executing several co-routines with my own custom made eventloop.

The asyncio event loop is well-tested and can be easily extended to acknowledge non-asyncio events. If you describe the actual use case, it might be easier to help. But if your goal is to *learn* about async programming and coroutines, read on.

> I'm curious if i can write my own eventloop without importing asyncio at all

It's definitely possible - asyncio itself is just a library, after all - but it will take some work for your event loop to be useful. See [this excellent talk](https://youtu.be/MCs5OvhV9S4) by David Beazley where he demonstrates writing an event loop in front of a live audience. (Don't be put off by David using the older `yield from` syntax - `await` works exactly the same way.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i found an example somewhere (sorry, don't remember where, no link), and changed a little bit.

An `eventloop` and `co-routins` without even importing `asyncio`:

```
import datetime
import heapq
import types
import time

class Task:
    def __init__(self, wait_until, coro):
        self.coro = coro
        self.waiting_until = wait_until

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.waiting_until == other.waiting_until

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.waiting_until < other.waiting_until

class SleepingLoop:
    def __init__(self, *coros):
        self._new = coros
        self._waiting = []

    def run_until_complete(self):
        # Start all the coroutines.
        for coro in self._new:
            wait_for = coro.send(None)
            heapq.heappush(self._waiting, Task(wait_for, coro))

        # Keep running until there is no more work to do.
        while self._waiting:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            # Get the coroutine with the soonest resumption time.
            task = heapq.heappop(self._waiting)
            if now < task.waiting_until:
                # We're ahead of schedule; wait until it's time to resume.
                delta = task.waiting_until - now
                time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
            try:
                # It's time to resume the coroutine.
                wait_until = task.coro.send(now)
                heapq.heappush(self._waiting, Task(wait_until, task.coro))
            except StopIteration:
                # The coroutine is done.
                pass


@types.coroutine
def async_sleep(seconds):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    wait_until = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
    actual = yield wait_until

    return actual - now


async def countdown(label, total_seconds_wait, *, delay=0):
    print(label, 'waiting', delay, 'seconds before starting countdown')
    delta = await async_sleep(delay)
    print(label, 'starting after waiting', delta)
    while total_seconds_wait:
        print(label, 'T-minus', total_seconds_wait)
        waited = await async_sleep(1)
        total_seconds_wait -= 1
    print(label, 'lift-off!')


def main():
    loop = SleepingLoop(countdown('A', 5, delay=0),
                        countdown('B', 3, delay=2),
                        countdown('C', 4, delay=1))
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    loop.run_until_complete()

    print('Total elapsed time is', datetime.datetime.now() - start)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```