# write an eventloop instead of using existing asyncio evenloop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, event-loop

Ok, so one can write a custom made **eventloop** over using given **asyncio**'s eventloop ([Writing an EventLoop without using asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767355/writing-an-eventloop-without-using-asyncio))

Now the question rises is why? Why prefer writing a custom made over **asyncio**'s eventloop?

Comment: I believe it's legacy. asyncio is new in Python standard, and was "usable" before keywords "async" and "await". For exemple, the web framework Tornado can use a non blocking API, without asyncio. But I believe today, the best practice is to use AsyncIO.

Answer (score 3):

> Why prefer writing a custom made over asyncio's eventloop?

Usually you invent something new if existing approach doesn't fit your needs. Or may be if you think you can do things more efficiently or conveniently.

First of all it worth noting that asyncio itself provides [multiple event loop implementations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#available-event-loops). Reason for this is that they built on top of different low-level OS API an can [behave differently](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#platform-support). You can select (or write your own event loop) that fits your task best.

Sometimes people create their own event loop implementations for better performance. Good example of such case is [uvloop](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop).

Sometimes people create event loops on top of other non-asyncio event loops. For example [quamash](https://github.com/harvimt/quamash) provides event loop on top of [Qt](https://www.qt.io/). It allows to write asynchronous programs using PyQt.

Comment: While on the topic of alternative event loops, you might want to also mention [curio](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio) and [trio](https://github.com/python-trio/trio), event loops written without the goal of asyncio compatibility and differing from it in both philosophy and implementation.