# Can I run Python Coroutines without asyncio?

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine

I'm trying understand if asyncio is a necessary part of the Python definition of coroutines or simply a convenience package.

Can I run this program without asyncio?

```
import time

async def clk():
    time.sleep(0.1)

async def process():
    for _ in range(2):
        await clk();
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("I am DONE waiting!")

def run():
    await process()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I get the error that `run()` is not defined with `async`, which I get, but there seems to be an infinite regress to the top.  Interestingly, this code runs (without the run() function) in Jupyter notebook.  I just type `await process`.

Comment: You need some kind of event loop to run coroutines, and asyncio provides the standard one (see e.g. `asyncio.run`). Jupyter conveniently hides this from you, but it still executes it with the help of asyncio: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html#internals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run async functions, you need to provide an event loop. One of the main functionalities of `asyncio` is to provide such a loop: when you execute `asyncio.run(process)` it provides a loop internally.

The reason why this code works in a notebook is that Jupyter (as well as the `ipython` REPL) provides a loop under the hood; there are other third-party libraries that provide a loop, such as `trio` and `curio`.

That being said, you can freely provide your own loop instead of using a library, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970666/122033). But in practice there is no point in doing that as `asyncio` is part of the Python standard library.